# Несоответствие передаваемых типов

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

```
DataBaseProvider provider = new DataBaseProvider("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

var command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = "execute AddPosts @id,'@postText','@postDate',0,0;";
command.Connection = provider.OpenConnection();

SqlParameter idParametr = new SqlParameter("@id", currentUser.ID);
SqlParameter postTextParametr = new SqlParameter("@postText", EnteringText.Text);
SqlParameter postDateParametr = new SqlParameter("@postDate", DateTime.Now);

command.Parameters.Add(idParametr);
command.Parameters.Add(postTextParametr);
command.Parameters.Add(postDateParametr);

var writer = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.Connection.Close();
```

При передаче идет конфликт, выдает ошибку, мол я вместо даты в БД передаю nvarchar вместо date. Скажите что я не так делаю. В БД параметр @postDate имеет тип данных date.

Comment: попробуйте указать тип параметра: command.Parameters.Add(
    "@postDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

Comment: нет не помогло, та же ошибка

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос снят. Я реализовал данный вопрос иначе - со стороны сервера.

1. Переписал процедуру с использование функции GetDate()

   ```
   create procedure AddPosts 
   @userid bigint ,
   @posttext nvarchar(2500),
   @postdate date,
   @like bigint,
   @comment bigint
   as insert into  Posts(UserId,PostText,PostDate,[Like],Comment)  
   values  (@userid,@posttext,getdate(),@like,@comment);
   ```
2. После чего переписал вышеуказанный код удалив не параметр с которым у меня случился затык:

   ```
   DataBaseProvider provider = new DataBaseProvider("dz.database.windows.net", "SosialNW", "dz_admin", "Be4218ak");
   //Не вшивать данные авторизации в прогу, а написать App.config 

   var command = new SqlCommand();
   command.CommandText = "execute AddPosts @id,'@postText',' ',0,0;";
   command.Connection = provider.OpenConnection();

   SqlParameter idParametr = new SqlParameter("@id", currentUser.ID);
   SqlParameter postTextParametr = new SqlParameter("@postText", EnteringText.Text);

   command.Parameters.Add(idParametr);
   command.Parameters.Add(postTextParametr);

   var writer = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

   command.Connection.Close();
   ```

Comment: Пометьте свой ответ как верный (галочка слева).